# Order of growth of specific recursive function

Tags: c#, math, recursion, big-o

What is the order of growth of the following function?

```
    static int counter = 0;

    static void Example(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            counter++;
        }

        Example(n / 2);
    }
```

In order to solve it I have done the following:

I first got rid of the inner for loop in order to end up with:

```
    static void Example(int n)
    {
        if (n == 1) return;            

        counter++;

        Example(n / 2);
    }
```

By analyzing that I was able to tell that the order of growth of that method was log base 2 of n .

so I am thinking that the final answer will be log base 2 times something else. How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at both the original and the modified function.  In the original function, you have the following amount of work done:

- A constant amount of work for the base case check.
- O(n) work to count up the number.
- The work required for a recursive call to something half the size.

We can express this as a recurrence relation:

- T(1) = 1
- T(n) = n + T(n / 2)

Let's see what this looks like.  We can start expanding this out by noting that

> T(n) = n + T(n / 2)
>
> = n + (n / 2 + T(n / 4)
>
> = n + n/2 + T(n / 4)
>
> = n + n/2 + (n / 4 + T(n / 8))
>
> = n + n/2 + n/4 + T(n / 8)

We can start to see a pattern here.  If we expand out the T(n / 2) bit k times, we get

> T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + n/2<sup>k</sup> + T(n/2<sup>k</sup>)

Eventually, this stops when n / 2<sup>k</sup> = 1.  When this happens, we have

> T(n) = n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1

What does this evaluate to?  Interestingly, this sum is equal to 2n + 1, because the sum n + n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... = 2n.  Consequently, this first function is O(n).  We could have also arrived at this conclusion by using the **[Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem)**, but it's interesting to see this approach as well.

---

So now let's look at the new function.  This one does

- A constant amount of work for the base case check.
- The work required for a recursive call to something half the size.

We can write this recurrence as

- T(1) = 1
- T(n) = 1 + T(n / 2)

Using the same trick as before, let's expand out T(n):

> T(n) = 1 + T(n / 2)
>
> = 1 + 1 + T(n / 4)
>
> = 1 + 1 + 1 + T(n / 8)

More generally, after expanding out k times, we get

> T(n) = k + T(n / 2<sup>k</sup>)

This stops when n / 2<sup>k</sup> = 1, which happens when k = log<sub>2</sub> n (that is, lg n).  In this case, we get that

> T(n) = lg n + T(1) = lg n + 1

So T(n) = O(lg n) in this case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So that means that it has the same order of growth as the same method without the inner for loop? That is interesting. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: @TonoNam- I think that you've misread my answer.  The inner for loop actually makes the code exponentially slower - without the loop it's O(log n), and with the loop it's O(n).

Comment: I really like the explanation by templatetypedef.

Comment: @templatetypedef Upvote for just explaining it so beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's see now.. this will add 1 to the counter n times.
each call n is reduced by half until it reaches one.

You can get rid of the loop and use

```
counter+=n;
```

instead, because basically the loop adds n to counter, 1 by one.

This means that n will be added to the counter each time it runs, and then become smaller by 2 until it reaches one.

so say n = 40.
counter:
40 -> 60 -> 70 -> 75 -> 77 -> 77.
n:
40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 5 -> 2 -> 1.

Just a push in the right direction (counter+=n; being the important part)

Comment: So the order of growth will equal to what? I actually need to find the order of growth of that algorithm not the number of times it will get executed... Thanks for the help though

Comment: in that case templaetypedev 's answer is precisely what you need, sorry for misunderstanding the question.