# Find the theta notation of the following recursive method

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have the homework question:

> Let T(n) denote the number of times the statement x = x + 1 is
>   executed in the algorithm

```
example (n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
       return
    }
    for i = 1 to n
    {
       x = x + 1
    }
    example (n/2)
}
```

> Find the theta notation for the number of times x = x + 1 is executed.
>   (10 points).

### here is what I have done:

we have the following amount of work done:
- A constant amount of work for the base case check
- O(n) work to count up the number
- The work required for a recursive call to something half the size

We can express this as a recurrence relation:
    T(1) = 1
    T(n) = n + T(n/2)

Let’s see what this looks like. We can start expanding this out by noting that

```
T(n)=n+T(n/2)
=n+(n/2+T(n/4))
=n+n/2+T(n/4)
=n+n/2+(n/4+T(n/8))
=n+n/2+n/4+T(n/8)
```

We can start to see a pattern here. If we expand out the T(n/2) bit k times, we get:
    T(n)=n+n/2+n/4+⋯+n/2^k +T(n/2^k )

Eventually, this stops when `n/2^k =1`  when this happens, we have:
     T(n)=n+n/2+n/4+n/8+⋯+1

What does this evaluate to? Interestingly, this sum is equal to 2n+1 because the sum `n+ n/2 + n/4 + n/8 +…. = 2n.`  Consequently this first function is **O(n)**

**I got that answer thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9509103/637142) answered by [@templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501557/templatetypedef)**

---

Know I am confused with the theta notation. will the answer be the same? I know that the theta notation is supposed to bound the function with a lower and upper limit. that means I need to functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the answer will be the same!

You can easily use the same tools to prove `T(n) = Omega(n)`.

After proving `T(n)` is both `O(n)` [upper asymptotic bound] and `Omega(n)` [lower asymptotic bound], you know it is also `Theta(n)` [tight asymptotic bound]

In your example, it is easy to show that `T(n) >=  n` - since it is homework, it is up to you to understand why.

Comment: Yeah is the same approach as the other question you answered. I placed dome edits on the question take a look at it. thanks again for everything